# Legendre transform of simple sum of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-optimization, legendre-transformation

Let
$$F(m, b) = H_1(m) + H_2(m, b)$$
where $H_2(m, b) = m G\left(\frac{b}{m}\right)$ and $m > 0$.

I want to compute the Legendre Transform of $F$.
The Legendre Transform of $H_2$ is well known :
$$H_2^\star(\phi, \psi) = \begin{cases}+\infty & \text{if } \phi + G^\star(\psi) > 0 \\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$

A simple way to compute this Legendre transform is as this :
$$\begin{align}
F^\star(\phi, \psi) & = \sup_{m > 0, b} \phi m + \psi b - H_1(m) - H_2(m, b)\\\\
& = \sup_{m > 0, b} \phi m + \psi b - H_1(m) - m G\left(\frac{b}{m}\right) \\\\
& = \sup_{m > 0} \left(\phi m - H_1(m) + m\sup_{b} \psi \frac{b}{m} - G\left(\frac{b}{m}\right) \right) \\\\
& = \sup_{m > 0} \left(\phi m - H_1(m) + m G^\star(\psi) \right) \\\\
& = H_1^\star(\phi + G^\star(\psi))
\end{align}$$

Another way is using inf-conv which is where I fail :
$$\begin{align}
F^\star(\phi, \psi) & = \inf \left\{ H_1^\star(\phi - \phi^\prime) + \iota_0(\psi - \psi^\prime) + H_2^\star(\phi^\prime, \psi^\prime) | \phi^\prime, \psi^\prime\right\} \\\\
& = \inf \left\{ H_1^\star(\phi - \phi^\prime) | \phi^\prime + G^\star(\psi) \leq 0\right\} 
\end{align}$$

But then I don't understand how to show the constraint is saturated, unless $H_1$ is isotone.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
F^\star(\phi, \psi) & = \inf \left\{ H_1^\star(\phi - \phi^\prime) + \iota_0(\psi - \psi^\prime) + H_2^\star(\phi^\prime, \psi^\prime) | \phi^\prime, \psi^\prime\right\} \\
& = \inf \left\{ H_1^\star(\phi - \phi^\prime) | \phi^\prime + G^\star(\psi) \leq 0\right\} \\
& = \inf_{\phi^\prime + G^\star(\psi) \leq 0} \sup_{m > 0} (\phi - \phi^\prime)m - H_1(m) \\
& \geq \sup_{m > 0} \inf_{\phi^\prime + G^\star(\psi) \leq 0}  (\phi - \phi^\prime)m - H_1(m) \\
& \geq \sup_{m > 0} (\phi + G^\star(\psi))m - H_1(m) \\
& \geq H_1(\phi + G^\star(\psi))
\end{align}$$

Then the rest follows.